# Azure Monitor Logs No Results Found

Tags: azure, azure-monitor

I do have a Windows VM in Azure. I also have an Azure Log Analytics Workspace setup and I've installed/enabled the following agents on the VM:

[image: log agents]

I would like to see logs in the Log Analytics Workspace but unfortunately as result of (almost any) log query I always get "No results found". I can't even see performance logs.

What am I missing to see logs in Azure Monitor logs?

Comment: While configuring the diagnostic settings to publish logs into log analytics workspace have you enabled performance counters as shown in [this](https://i.imgur.com/lCEQpit.png) image.

Comment: If you have enabled the performance counters from the diagnostics settings & in workspace if you are able to see the Perf table would suggest you to click on [Preview Data](https://i.imgur.com/7rsxxLf.png) and check the logs as show in this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7wQ4.gif)

Comment: thanks. I did all the setup you suggested. Strange, I do not see the Performance table. Why? But I can access to Preview Data of other table..

Comment: Doubt: in the Diagnostic Settings of the VM I have linked/created the Storage Account for the Agent. Do I have to link it to the Log Analytics Workspace  (using the Workspace Data Sources/Storage accounts logs tab)?

Comment: While enabling the diagnostics settings of the VM it will ask you to create a new storage account or to select the existing storage account as shown in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/E0zaxKs.png)

Comment: When you are trying to enable insights on your VM,  from the portal. it triggers a new deployment to install `Dependency Agent Windows' & post the deployment you can see a  message that all data is getting published to which log analytics workspace as shown in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/MmkvoHX.png). Would suggest you check to which workspace the logs are getting published & run the queries from there.

Comment: It looks I solved by using the "Agent Configuration" tab in the workspace. Before it was empty. Can it be this was the issue?